# How to integrate the Bootstrap modal component with Phoenix?

Tags: bootstrap-modal, phoenix-framework

I'm no fan of the blocking browser confirmation dialogues currently used for delete confirmations by [phoenix_html](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html). Given that Phoenix ships with Bootstrap by default, how do I integrate the [Bootstrap modal component](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) with Phoenix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented the delegation of this dialogue to a Bootstrap modal component if (and only if) jQuery is available and a suitable DOM element is present.

1. Copy this [modal.js](https://gist.github.com/marceloomens/e4e9927fa715e00095fd8e04c7195a43) gist to the `web/static/js` folder in your Phoenix project.
2. Comment out the `import "phoenix_html"` line in `web/static/js/app.js`
3. Include the HTML for a Bootstrap modal component in your HTML template. The Bootstrap documentation advises to:

   > Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in
   >   your document to avoid other components affecting the modal's
   >   appearance and/or functionality.

Make sure that your HTML includes the `id="phoenix-bs-modal"` on the top-level `<div class="modal">`, and that a primary (confirmation) button `<button class="btn-primary">` is present in the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="phoenix-bs-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

The message passed in via the `data-confirm` attribute on the delete link is forwarded to the modal body.

This has been useful for me to get a coherent layout. I'm putting my solution out there because hopefully it's useful to others as well.